# cannot resolve symbol NgxPaginationModule

Tags: angular5, ngx-pagination

I am trying to use NgxPaginationModule in my Angular5 project **cannot resolve symbol NgxPaginationModule**, I followed all step as documented

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GlobalModule } from './global/global.module';
import { ProtectedModule} from './protetcted/protect-module.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';//cannot resolve symbol NgxPaginationModule


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    GlobalModule,
    ProtectedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxPaginationModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I checked node modules and ngx-pagination folder exist.
Can any one suggest what is causing this error?

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

This same thing is happening to me during an Azure CI build:

> Could not resolve ngx-pagination relative to D:/a/7/s/src/app/app.module.ts.
> Cannot find module 'ngx-pagination'

app.module.ts:

```
// import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination'; // <-- import the module
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    // NgxPaginationModule
  ],
```

Works fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and tried deleting *node_modules* and *package-lock.json* and then reinstalling everything with `npm -i`.
It worked for me.